# What is the best approach to store logged in user details in MVVM?

Tags: android, mvvm

I have an E-commerce android app in which the user should be signed in to perform some functions (Adding product to cart, Marking product as favorites etc) and there are some function which would work without signing in. (Searching products)

So whenever an user tries to perform a function which requires signing, I have to switch to an activity to sign-in the user.
Users are signed in using Firebase authentication (Google provider).

What is the best approach (in **MVVP**) to store user details (like Firebase user id, name etc) to be accessible in the app globally (in all required activities).

Possible solution (I came up with):
1. One `ViewModel` to store logged in user details, which is accessed in all required `activities`. (Using this as of now)
2. To use shared preferences to store user details.
3. Using global data variable by using a class extending Application.

If any alternate approach is better than specified ones, please do mention !

Comment: 1) Authentication details don't belong in a view model - as the name suggests 2) Is this secure enough i.e rooted phones 3) If it needs to be accessible for the lifetime of the application class then this is the correct scope - suggest you extend `Supplier<T>` interface for abstraction.  For alternates you could always store user details using firebase.

Comment: @MarkKeen I want to store details like name ,id etc which don't require much security (I had mistakenly used "authentication details" instead of "user details").

Comment: Then I'd suggest shared preferences if it's non sensitive information, which you can still implement a supplier class for as it's just implementation changes only.

Comment: If you are interested in a clean Firebase authentication, you can check this [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-create-a-clean-firebase-authentication-using-mvvm-37f9b8eb7336).